# Visual Studio / TFVC - Check-In / Check-out

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, checkin

I'm new to development in Visual Studio / TFS.  I'm working on a team that uses TFVC for their version control.  I created a project and then checked it in.  It deployed fine at the nightly build.  A week later, I made a change to one page and then checked in just that page.  It seems like my change didn't take affect after their nightly build.  I then noticed that the check in option was available at the folder that contained my project.  So I checked it and it recognized that there were changes to be checked in.

So, if I make a small change to one page or item in a project, can't I check in just that one item?  Or do I have to check it in from the top level folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can check in just one item.  Depending on the version of Visual Studio you're using, it's done in slightly different ways:

**VS2010:**

1. Open Pending Changes (View -> Other Windows -> Pending Changes
2. In the Pending Changes window, uncheck the item(s) you don't want to check in

**VS2012+:**

1. Open Team Explorer (View -> Team Explorer)
2. Click on the Team Explorer header (Right below the Back/Forward/Home/Refresh button ribbon)
3. Click 'Pending Changes'
4. Under the "Included Changes", right-click the item(s) and/or folder(s) you don't want to check in and choose 'Exclude"